# Does the set $A$, of all permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that fixes $2$ and $4$ form a subgroup of $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Does the set $A$, of all permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that fixes $2$ and $4$ form a subgroup of $S_4$?

I’ve got as far,
The set $A$ will be the identity where all $4$ numbers map to themselves (as all fixed) and $(1, 3)$ as $2$ and $4$ are fixed. So the set $A =\{\operatorname{id}, (1 3)\}$

Now I need to show that this is a sub group of $S_4$, by identity closure and inverses.

Identity is in both so ok but I’m stuck on the other $2$.

Any help would be great

Kara x

Comment: Well tell us what you got when you calculated $e^2, e\cdot (13), (13)\cdot e, (13)\cdot(13)$. Then we can see ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each such permutation has the form $\pi = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &x_4 \end{pmatrix}$ with $x_2=2$ and $x_4=4$.

Show that the composition of two such permutations has the same shape.

Moreover show that the inverse permutation of such a permutation has the same format.

You're right about the structure of $A$, consisting of $(1)(2)(3)(4)$ and $(13)(2)(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}$Note that
$$
\id\circ \id = \id,\ \id \circ (13) = (13),\ (13)\circ\id = (13),\ \text{and}\ (13)\circ (13) = \id.
$$
So any product of elements of $A$ is an element of $A$.
Furthermore
$$
\id^{-1} = \id,\ \text{and}\ (13)^{-1} = (13).
$$
So also any inverse of an element of $A$ is an element of $A$.

---

You can also see that without even considering the elements of $A$ one by one. If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are permutations fixing $2$ and $4$, note that
$$
(\sigma\circ \tau)(2) = \sigma(\tau(2)) = \sigma(2) = 2,
$$
so $\sigma\circ \tau$ fixes $2$. By the same reasoning $\sigma\circ\tau$ fixes $4$ as well and $\tau\circ\sigma$ also fixes $2$ and $4$.

Furthermore, since $\sigma(2)=2$ you also have $\sigma^{-1}(2)=2$ and since $\sigma(4)=4$ you also have $\sigma^{-1}(4)=4$, so the inverse of any element of $A$ also fixes $2$ and $4$ and hence is an element of $A$ as well.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct: $A=\{{\rm id}, (13)\}$.

I will use the [two-step subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Two-Step_Subgroup_Test).

Observe that $\varnothing \neq A\subseteq S_4$.

Consider the multiplication table for $A$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\circ & {\rm id} & (13) \\
\hline
{\rm id} & {\rm id} & (13) \\
(13) & (13) & {\rm id}.
\end{array}$$

From the table, one can see that for any $a,b\in A$, we have $a\circ b\in A.$

Since $(13)^{-1}=(13)\in A$ and ${\rm id}^{-1}={\rm id}\in A$, $A$ is closed under inverses.

Hence $A\le S_4$.